# Where to read the source code of azure vm serial console?

Tags: azure, console, virtual-machine

I want to apply serial console function to my own application, like clicking a button then it will pop out a serial console of the vm, so need to read the source code to know how to mock the request, the sdk can't meet my request.There are many open source repo from azure in github, I'm not clear which one is the right one.Looking forward to the reply, thx!

Comment: Hey @geisajiamanshang Have you gone through this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/serial-console-windows

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT, hi, it introduces the functions, but  I want to mock the url that can get the serial console of a vm. like this'GET
 wss://gateway16.southeastasia.console.azure.com/n/cc-1a3c9c42/cc-1a3c9c42/serialTerminals/fa4c0a89bc57c0272040821ca4ef3a08/client', got from the terminal when accessing console in azure portal

Comment: how to customize the request to get the serial console, the sdk not provide this, only provide enable/disable/get status/ of it, not I need.